# Increment a column if string appears in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to increment the s_number column if the word "LIVE" appears in another column. The first column will always be "LIVE", and then any occurrence of "LIVE" will always be in a group of 2. I want to increment the s_number column after the second occurrence, I'm not sure how to go about this

```
 Electric  s_number
   LIVE      1
   EARTH     1
   NEUTRAL   1
   NEUTRAL   1
   LIVE      1
   LIVE      2
   EARTH     2
   NEUTRAL   2
```

Comment: you can create a column and fill it with `Electric.shift(-1)` then you can look into this new column.

Comment: Can LIVE be in a group of 3 (or more) ever? If so, what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift` and the `column` itself to create the bool , then do `cumsum`

```
((df.Electric=='LIVE')&(df.Electric.shift()=='LIVE')).cumsum()+1
Out[278]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: Electric, dtype: int32
```